# While using the D3 library is there any way to force a transformation to happen immediately

Tags: d3.js

So as mention I want to force a transformation to happen in a for loop rather than waiting for the loop to end.  The reason I wish to do this is because I'm trying to call an index of an array of d3 data.  My ultimate goal is to have 3 nodes follow a path of GPS coordinates the json is laid out as such { ID: 1 [[ lat , lon , time],[lat2, lon, time2]], ID: 2...} thus I'm trying to check the time scamp inside the transformation and only recieveing the last entry. I am using this and overlaying it with poly maps here is the chunk of code I am dealing with

```
for(var i = 1; i < layers.length -1; i++){
        var t = layers[i].transition().duration(3000);
        var l = 0
        var j = 0
        var help = map.extent()[0].lon;
        var help2 = map.extent()[1].lon;
        var scale = (templon1 - templon2) / (help - help2); 

        t.selectAll(".t1")
        .attr("transform",function(d){
            x = map.locationPoint({lon: d[0][1], lat: d[0][0]});
            d = map.locationPoint({lon: d[5000][1], lat: d[5000][0]});
            l = d.x - x.x
            j = d.y - x.y
            return ("translate(" + l / scale + "," + j / scale + ")"); 

        });
        t.selectAll(".t2")
        .attr("transform",function(d){
            x = map.locationPoint({lon: d[0][1], lat: d[0][0]});
            d = map.locationPoint({lon: d[5000][1], lat: d[5000][0]});
            l = d.x - x.x
            j = d.y - x.y
            return ("translate(" + l / scale + "," + j / scale + ")"); 
        });
    }
```